# Google Maps Javascript API: Exclude transit types from transit route?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm using the `directionsService` from the Google Maps API to find the transit routes (`travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.TRANSIT`) between two points. However, I would like to only find train routes, which means that instead of taking a bus/metro, the user would have to walk that part. So instead of:

`14:30 - Take bus to New York Train Station (10 mins)
14:40 - Take train to Chicago Train Station (60 mins)
15:40 - Take bus to restaurant (5 mins)
15:45 - Arrived at restaurant!`

The route would look like this:

`14:20 - Walk to New York Train Station (20 mins)
14:40 - Take train to Chicago Train Station (60 mins)
15:40 - Walk to restaurant (10 mins)
15:50 - Arrived at restaurant!`

This is possible in Google Maps (when you click `Options` --> `Preferences`, you can exclude the bus and metro), but how can I do this in the JavaScript API?

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I just found the answer myself. It can be accomplished by adding `transitOptions: { modes: [google.maps.TransitMode.TRAIN] }` to the `directionsService.route` options.

I hope this will help others with the same question!